# retail flotation

Tags: meaning, terminology

> When it comes to using the environment to sell, the Body Shop is a pioneer. The Body Shop shot to fame in the 1980s. It stood for environmental awareness and an ethical approach to business. But its success was as much to do with what it sold as what it stood for. It sold natural cosmetics, Raspberry Ripple Bathing Bubbles and Chamomile Shampoo, products that were immensely popular with consumers. Its stock exchange listing in 1984 was one of the most successful **retail flotations** in history.

What do you think *retail flotation* is?

Comment: Clues to an answer are [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_float).

Comment: So there are two ways to spell flotation/floatation, with the latter apparently confined to stock-market environment.  note that "stock floatation" does not appear in Google Books BrE or AmE corpus; only "stock flotation." the OP's quote spelled it "flotation".  The alternate spelling "Floatation" is apparently an Americanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **flotation** is a method companies can use to generate money. Instead of being privately owned, they sell portions (shares) of the company to the public. The public then plays a part in the everyday running of the company, typically by being able to vote to influence decisions. In return, as the value of the company fluctuates, the value of the shares goes up or down.

**Retail** is any business involving direct contact with the public. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retail):

> Retail is the process of selling consumer goods and/or services to customers through multiple channels of distribution to earn a profit.

The Body Shop is a (primarily) retail business, and it floated on the stock market in 1984, and this **retail flotation** was one of the more successful flotations ever.

So **Retail Flotation** is the flotation of a retail company.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is an allowable alternate spelling, but "stock floatation" hasn't made it into the corpus. Perhaps it's common on the internet. I'll check.

Comment: well, "stock floatation" does occur on internet, but in my browser I don't get ghit counts. Also, Google Search tries to redirect to "stock flotation".